# Serialize an object into SQL Server using C#

Tags: c#, max, varbinary

I have the following code which writes to a SQL Server database:

```
private void InsertResult(Result results, string messageId)
{
   object chkresult = (results);

   MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
   StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(memStream);

   sw.Write(chkresult);

   SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Reporting"].ConnectionString);

   using (conn)
   {
      using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
      {
         conn.Open();

         cmd.CommandText = "Results_Ins";
         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = messageId;
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@result", SqlDbType.VarBinary, Int32.MaxValue);
         cmd.Parameters["@result"].Value = memStream.GetBuffer();
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@RowCount", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

         cmd.Connection = conn;

         try
         {
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
         catch (Exception err)
         {
             // handle the error
             //messageInsert = false;
         }
         finally
         { 
             conn.Close(); 
         }
      }
   }

   //return rowCount;
}
```

When I execute this code, I get 0x being stored in the `Result` column. I'm not sure this is correct, and therefore I need some help.

Basically, I need to store a complete object into a single column in a SQL Server database table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to call [`Flush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.flush.aspx) or cause `sw` to be [`Close`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.close.aspx)d or [`Dispose`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.dispose.aspx)d in order to ensure that it's finished writing to the `memStream`.

Also, instead of [`GetBuffer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.getbuffer.aspx), you should use [`ToArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray.aspx). [`GetBuffer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.getbuffer.aspx) returns an internal buffer which may be larger than the amount of bytes that have actually been written.

---

You should also change this:

```
catch (Exception err)
{
   // handle the error
   //messageInsert = false;
}
```

to only catch **specific** exceptions for which you have a strategy to deal with them.

---

And, even now, I don't think it's going to do what you **wanted** (which you haven't really spelled out). All that your `sw.Write` call does [is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfc2b8zk.aspx):

> Writes the text representation of an object to the text string or stream by calling the **ToString** method on that object.

If you want actual *serialization* to occur, you're going to need to write code that causes it to happen - after picking whether you want to perform [binary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72hyey7b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/90c86ass.aspx) serialization.

Comment: Hi Damien, so making the suggestive changes has now stored ServiceReference1.Result in th field. So, the object (which was from a webservice) appears to be saved now. have you any examples on how to convert this back?

Comment: @CSharpNewBee - note my most recent addition at the bottom - all that you're currently storing is the result of calling `ToString()` on `results` - which by default is just the type name. You need to decide what type of serialization you actually want to perform (I've linked to the two standard .NET ones) and then write the code to do that.

Comment: I see, our messages passed each other :-) So, i am only storing the name to the object. perhaps, i need to do some more reading, as i thought this method would write the object.